# Java SQL Exception Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, sqlexception

This seems to be a frequent question around here, but no specific answer. I've never encountered the issue before. The code is here:

```
public static Reservation retrieveReservation()throws IOException,
   SQLException{
   Reservation testRsv = new Reservation();
   try {
      Connection con = null;

      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      con=DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@wewe",
         "ewew",
         "sdsds");
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      try {
         PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT *
         FROM SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES WHERE id = ?");
         ResultSet rset = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
         prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
         prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
         prepareStatement.close();
         con.commit();
         if(rset.next()){
            retrievedID = rset.getString("ID");
            Blob blob = rset.getBlob("RESERVATIONINST");
            status = rset.getString("STATUS");
            long blobLength = blob.length();
            int pos = 1;   // position is 1-based
            int len = 10;
            byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(pos, len);
            InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
            testRsv = (Reservation)ois.readObject();
         }

         // System.out.println("Map Size: " + retrievedmap.size());
         rset.close();
         con.close();
      }catch(IOException ioe){
         System.err.print(ioe);
      }
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
      System.err.print(cnfe);
   }
   return testRsv;
}
```

it produces the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Any idea why?
I've re-checked the variables as parameters that is the ID and its not null and has a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the order of statement,

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
            SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES WHERE id = ?");
  prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
  ResultSet rset = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
```

remove these statement (don't close the connection while you are reading).

```
prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
prepareStatement.close();
con.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a statement requiring one parameter, execute it and only after that you set the parameter:

```
        PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
        SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES WHERE id = ?");
        ResultSet rset = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
        prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
```

this should work:

```
        PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM 
        SMD_RESERVATION_INSTANCES WHERE id = ?");
        prepareStatement.setString(1, localIDTest);
        ResultSet rset = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
```